# mysql 5.6 fix replication

Tags: mysql

I've just created a mysql 5.6 master/slave relationship automatically through my provider's API, meaning I didn't have a root user. So after the slave was setup, I enabled the root user on the slave, which of course broke replication. I need to skip that GTID, but I'm having difficulty understanding the howtos.

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GTID_NEXT="5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:10";
BEGIN; COMMIT;
SET GTID_NEXT="AUTOMATIC";
START SLAVE
```

results in the same error. What's the right GTID to select?

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space
                  Master_Host: 10.188.52.218
                  Master_User: slave_6b72a386
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: replica-1007782573-bin.000006
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1071986205
           Relay_Log_File: replica-1130155763-relay.000003
            Relay_Log_Pos: 5880
    Relay_Master_Log_File: replica-1007782573-bin.000002
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: No
          Replicate_Do_DB:
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 1396
               Last_Error: Error 'Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE USER 'root'@'%''
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 5644
          Relay_Log_Space: 5370067417
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error:
           Last_SQL_Errno: 1396
           Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE USER 'root'@'%''
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
         Master_Server_Id: 1007782573
              Master_UUID: 5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10
         Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                SQL_Delay: 0
      SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
  Slave_SQL_Running_State:
       Master_Retry_Count: 86400
              Master_Bind:
  Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
 Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 141223 15:14:12
           Master_SSL_Crl:
       Master_SSL_Crlpath:
       Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:9-5851
        Executed_Gtid_Set: 08bc8aa0-8a7a-11e4-8f2d-001851502460:1-41,
5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:9-69
            Auto_Position: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the executed GTID set.

```
Executed_Gtid_Set: 08bc8aa0-8a7a-11e4-8f2d-001851502460:1-41,
                   5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:9-69
```

`08bc8aa0-8a7a-11e4-8f2d-001851502460` is probably your slave, your master is

```
Master_UUID: 5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10
```

as you can see some lines above. From the master you have therefore executed transactions 9 - 69. So the next GTID is 70.

Also note, that you should set `Auto_Position: 1` with a `CHANGE MASTER TO` statement. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-howto.html).

Comment: '5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:9-70' didn't work, said I couldn't set it to that. but 
'5b182ac6-8a79-11e4-8f28-001851cf5e10:70' did work. I must be still misunderstanding something, but it's working now.